# Multi project solution "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0," not giving a project name

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a Solution with many different project types in (Class File, ASP.net MVC 5, ASP.net Core 2.1). When I try and build the Solution I get this error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web.Mvc, Version=5.2.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

However, there is no associated project name. Project, File, Line are all empty.

How can I find out which project is causing the error? How can I trouble shoot this?

I can find various Google results for the particular error - but if the compiler doesn't even tell me which project is at fault - how can I begin to fix it?

Thanks.

Update:
What are the valid reasons for the compiler not supplying the name of the project at fault, if any?

Comment: Have you checked the output window? Sometimes it contains some information error window doesn't show.

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio, use diagnostic logs to distinguish which project causes that issue.

Comment: It must be a project that references `System.Web.Mvc` for a start so it's unlikely (can't guarantee it though) to be a .Net Core or class library assembly.

Comment: @Mateusz Thanks - I've never sued diagnostic logs, can't find much on google - can you point me in the right direction please - is is something I have to enable?

Comment: @niico depending on how you're buiding your solution you can add parameter to your compile command ( like in [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/diagnostics-compiler-diagnostic-options) ) or just set it through options menu ( like in [here](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/677915) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**System.Web.Mvc** is a namespace used by MVC 5 so the error is likely occurring in your MVC 5 project (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/web-frameworks/dd492706(v=vs.118)).

One quick fix would be to ensure that the package is in your project. If you find that it's missing, generate a new project and copy over the binary from the bin directory of that project to your project.

Another thing you can try is deleting the reference to the package and adding it back.  This should resolve any dependency issues regarding a version mismatch or file reference error.

Comment: I actually rebooted the machine and reloaded the solution - now it's gone!??!

Comment: Restarting VS is often a way to resolve many strange errors. :)

Comment: Also - do you know why the error didn't include the name of the project causing the issue?

Comment: I actually have no idea!  But, I've certainly seen it happen before and it's no very helpful!